# regex allow first letter to be number

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am using the following regex.

```
/^(([0-9._]?)*([a-zA-Z._]|[a-zA-Z._][a-zA-Z0-9\-._]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\._)*([A-Za-z._]|[A-Za-z._][A-Za-z0-9\-._]*[A-Za-z0-9_])$/;
```

It fails for `1dsd.343.23fdf`

but passes `d1sd.343.23fdf`

what is to be modified on the regex to allow first letter as a number.

Comment: It seems you can just add matching a digit in a character class in the second part. https://regex101.com/r/rgOJL9/1 But what do you want to match with this pattern? I see there are also underscores, so for the current data there will be not match in the first part.

Comment: What are rules for your regex?

Comment: i am not an expert on regex...... Its just that the above regex get's the job done... all i want it to allow first character as number....it fails on 1dsd.343.23fdf

Comment: @RohitKumar You are welcome. Perhaps if you can list some other formats that should be allowed/rejected, maybe we can provide you with shorter pattern that would be a better fit.